# OCaml, default value for Unix.umask

Tags: unix, ocaml, umask

Consider this code :

```
#load "unix.cma" ;;
print_int (Unix.umask 0) ;;
print_newline () ;;
```

When I run it, I get 2 (binary : 000.000.010).
When I run it with 'sudo', I get 18 (binary : 000.010.010)
I was expected to get something like 0o640 (binary : 110.010.000), as the standard library says : http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#TYPEfile_perm
My purpose is to make a directory. If I make it with

```
(Unix.umask 0) lor (0o640)
```

it is created but inaccessible.
An accurate look at the binary numbers gives me the idea that the default mask could be reverted. So, I make a directory using this :

```
let revert_mask m =
  let user  = (m land 0b000000111) in
  let group = (m land 0b000111000) lsr 3 in
  let other = (m land 0b111000000) lsr 6 in
  (user lsl 6) lor (group lsl 3) lor other
;;
```

Then, I create my directory :

```
let mask = (revert_mask (Unix.umask 0)) lor 0o640 ;;
print_int mask ;;
print_newline () ;;
Unix.mkdir "foo" mask ;;
```

I get 416 (0o640), which corresponds to my

```
ls -l | grep foo
```

:

```
drw-r----- 2 (me) (me) 4096 june   2 19:23 foo
```

However, a

```
cd foo
```

won't work.

So, I'm stuck with ubuntu 14.04 and ocaml 4.01.0 toplevel.

Comment: When using `Unix.umask` for the first time, you should get the same value as the one you get from the command line (on bash) by running the shell builtin `umask`. It should be the two-complement of the access rights set for any created file on your behalf.

Comment: Besides, to access a directory, the execute bit must be set on the directory rights.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you linked to says:

> `type file_perm = int`
>   The type of file access rights, e.g. `0o640` is read and write for user, read for group, none for others

The `0o640` is an example, not the expected default value -- and it's an example `file_perm` value, not an example `umask` value.

I'm not familiar with OCaml, but in UNIX in general the umask is an attribute of each process, typically set to a default value but modifiable by calling the `umask` system call.

The bits of the umask are those that are turned *off* when creating a file or directory. For example, my current umask is `0022` (or, in OCaml syntax, `0o022`) -- which means that when I create a file or directory, the corresponding bits (write access for group and others) are turned *off*. Directories need execute permission, and files generally don't, so if I create a directory its default permissions will be `755` (`rwxr-xr-x`), and if I create a file its default permissions will be `644` (`rw-r--r--`).

`0o640` is not a sensible `umask` value.

Comment: The documentation reads : "mkdir ... file_perm...see Unix.umask". I thought that it would be the same for files and directories. However, the permissions for mkdir are those whose bits are turned on (I checked). So umask has no reason to be quoted in mkdir, has it ?

Comment: @sarpifeste: Assuming `Unix.mkdir` is intended to act like the UNIX `mkdir` system call, yes, `umask` is relevant. The `mode` or `file_perm` argument to `mkdir` is modified by the current `umask`. It may be that the OCaml documentation assumes familiarity with the corresponding UNIX system and library calls. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html

Comment: So there is no need in changing umask if I want to make a directory, and I don't have to mix file perm with umask.

Comment: @sarpifeste: Not in general, no. Your umask is generally either set in  a shell startup script (like `$HOME/.bashrc`) or left with whatever default your system provides. You get a different umask when running under `sudo` because `root` uses a different umask (`002` vs. `022`).

Answer (score 2):

To create a directory, just do this:

```
Unix.mkdir "/some/dir" 0o777
```

The operating system will automatically apply the current umask (which is why the documentation refers you to it - you don't actually need to call `umask` yourself).

Answer (score 1):

You need execute permission to cd to a directory. Don't deny yourself execute permission (the octal 100 bit).

(I have a feeling you're misunderstanding the purpose of umask, but that is a separate question.)